# Is it possible to pause or schedule my GCP Dataflow streaming pipeline to limit costs?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I've set up a GCP Dataflow streaming pipeline (using python for the template), and I am looking to limit the cost of the pipeline. I'm aware that streaming pipelines need a minimum of 1 worker, but is it possible to "pause" or start + stop the pipeline at given times in order to limit the cost of the pipeline running?

The only idea I've had so far is to run the pipeline through code in a cloud function, which is run on a cron job, but I feel like there are better solutions out there.

Any help appreciated!

Currently I haven't tried any cost-limiting measures except limiting the max number of workers for my job

Comment: well, from the best of my understanding, Dataflow is essentially a data streaming tool (in your context I guess), so to stop it - means to terminate/delete it. And to restart - means to redeploy/launch it again. Thus, you might delete and create the Dataflow job on some scheduler if you would like. That is obviously possible. For example you might like to do it using a cloud function, or using a cloud build service, or something else...

Comment: alternative (and that depends on - context, scope, budget, skills, time, non functional requirements, etc.) you might like to develop your solution using some other serverless services - cloud functions, cloud run, cloud build, etc.

Comment: There is a time slot where you are sure not to receive data ?
Do you really need having a streaming job (low latency...) ? if it's not the case you can also write a batch pipeline instead.